# Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::9000, killall && kill -9 are not working

Tags: node.js, linux, command-line, kill, kill-process

I have had to changed my localhost port 2 times because I cannot seem to close background nodemon/node function. Event restarting doesn't solve it.

When I run `ps -ax | grep 9000` the below is returned

`7204 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto 9000`

killall and kill -9 7204 both fail and if I run `ps -ax | grep 9000` again the pid number will change (which is my assumption for why it won't work). I received the same result if I replaced 9000 with `node` or `nodemon` like so:

`7732 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto node` or nodemon which will look the same. Also, when I run the grep command with for node, there are other processes but when I try to kill the above node process, it will tell me `bash: kill: (7732) - No such process` even though I can run it again and the same thing will show up with a different pid.

My goal is to kill this process and how to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: You are searching processes rather than ports. `7204` is the pid of your `grep` command, which matches `9000` because that's what it's currently searching for. When you run the next command, it's already exited because the search is done. You should be trying to kill `node`, not `grep`

Comment: What do you suggest I do to kill node directly if not to use the pid?

Comment: Use `node`'s pid, not `grep`'s pid

Comment: Isn't `7732 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto node` 7732 node's pid? Also, that is the specific pid that constantly changes, the other node processes do not if I re-search. I am only mentioning this because I cannot kill this pid because it constantly changes.

Comment: That pid is for the command `grep --color=auto node`. You can tell because the COMMAND section of the line is `grep --color=auto node`

Comment: I used `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 9000` from the post you linked. There was a pid of some sort in the middle. I killed it. Then running it with node or nodemon or 9000 will show nothing. If I run my application, then the `EARDDRINUSE :::9000` still occurs. When I run those commands again, it only shows 1 process on the tcp port. Once I close it normally, it goes away. Yet, whenever I restart my application, it still claims that the port is occupied?

Comment: Which program is it that has the port open?

Comment: If I run `ps -ax | grep 9000` or node or nodemon then it still shows`6841 pts/19   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto node`. So I assume that node/etc. is still running despite it not showing up on the tcp. I just discovered something odd. If I pass in the PORT from an .env then even if I change the port to say 9003, then it will say EARDDRINUSE despite it never running prior.

Comment: That is again the pid of `grep`. What does `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 9000` say?

Comment: That command says nothing if I close the application. But the curious thing is what happened when passing in the port through an .env file. Which is a little bizarre...

Comment: Sounds like your application tries to open the port twice

Comment: That must be it but no idea why. `app.listen(process.env.PORT);` Event passed in like that will cause the same problem. Anyways, thanks for working through this!

Comment: if this is not solved yet, try `pgrep npm` and `pgrep node` and kill their pid's